# fiware orion context broker - can not get token2

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I have the same problem like Vicens Fayos on 21.02.2015.
Was there any solution? You wrote it might be a network problem, but still?
I have orion image R4 running.
If I have my data on my own instance and I use the mashup to display the POI, I don't get any POI's on the map. Do I have - to make it work - deploy my own mashup envoriment on the orion instance? I don't get it...
If I use the public instance, how can I create a 'type' (as room for room1) of entity. OrionContentExplorer don't let me do that. Do you know why? 
I ask because I think about using the public instance - which works - for my data, but I need to provide the data with a type...
Hope you can help.

Greetings from Hamburg Speedup
Tim

P.S. On Saturday we have to pitch our viable produkt and POI Map should work somehow. Help would be great...

Comment: Please try to include more detail on your post. For example, when you tell "OrionContentExplorer don't let me do that" please explain what is the actual problem, e.g. the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason for the problem that I don't get data from my Instance
The Node Spain1 isn't working correct. when I look at 'Connections' I don't see the explanation how to connect via SSH, but get the info that i have to get an publi IP. Anywhy I could login to my instance and it was running. But nothing was displayed.
The problem how to provide the public instance with a object typ is solved. Problem makes the windows maschine I'm working on. I got help to do it from unix development environment.
Still the Orionexplorer don't let me create a object 'type', but that is - I think - not to be adressed to you.

Thanks
TimE